# java.lang.StackOverflowError between two classes

Tags: java, swing, inheritance

I'm trying to create a JFrame in one class and adding a JPanel to it in my main class, is this not possible?

This is my Main class

```
public class Main {

    JPanel p;
    JLabel lbl1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    Main() {

        new Window();

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel("Hello");
        p.add(lbl1);
    }

}
```

And the Window class

```
public class Window extends Main {
    Window() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(p);
    }

}
```

I get the exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: Why does your `Window` class extend `Main`? What makes it "the same" as `Main`?

Comment: Every `Window` is a `Main`, and the `Main` constructor creates another new `Window` — that is infinite recursion.

Comment: If I don't extend `Main` in `Window` class i can't do `frame.add(p)`. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: `Is there another way to do this? `  Yes, read the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Frames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) for basic examples. The tutorial contains all the Swing basics. Download the "FrameDemo" code and make changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Window class extends Main. When you call the constructor of a subclass class, the constructor of the parent class is called first.

In your case, you're calling the Window constructor in your Main constructor. The Window constructor call the Main constructor because of the inheritance, causing the StackOverflow : each constructor makes a call to the other one

Comment: Ok, but if I can't extend `Main` in `Window` class, how can I use `frame.add(p)`? `p` being the JPanel which is created in `Main` class.

Comment: If i'm not wrong, you can change the Window class in an inner class of Window. But the best way is to put your JPanel and JLabel in the window class. They don't really belong to the Main class